# Regex to search a multi-line field in a text file

Tags: regex, search, vim, notepad++

I have a text file of logs. In it I am interested in searching a field using some regular expression (I use notepad++ on Win, but even use vim on Ubuntu to parse/read this log text file so either one is ok)

The text file has entries as below.

```
src.type= DEVICE_1     <-- there is a space and then a newline char after the last letter which is 1
dst.type= ZONE_1
someparam1

src.type= DEVICE_1 
dst.type= ZONE_2
someparam2
```

Such entries keep repeating in the log text file.

I am interested in finding those lines which have DEVICE_1 in it but only for those occurrences which have a dst.type= ZONE_2 after it i.e.

I intend to find

```
src.type= DEVICE_1 
dst.type= ZONE_2
```

but not

```
src.type= DEVICE_1
dst.type= ZONE_1
```

Notepad++ allows searching using keywords as regexes. I could get a working regex or any other way (not necessarily involving regexes) to find such occurrences I am looking for in the text file.

I tried below in notepad++ search using regex without success:

```
src.type= DEVICE_1 \ndst.type= ZONE_2
```

Also tried `[ ]` character class.

How can I search for what I am looking to find?

Comment: If you're on Windows, a newline is actually two characters, a line feed and a carriage return.  Even if you open it in vim on Ubuntu, I think vim will recognize the Windows newline characters and make sure to preserve the formatting, so you may not be aware that the file is using Windows newline characters even though you're editing the file on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, use the following regex, with the ". matches newlines" checkbox enabled:

```
src.type= DEVICE_1\s+dst.type= ZONE_2
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Tried it in Notepad++ but did not work. Had the .matches newlines box checked.  Can't find text is what notepad says

Comment: Weird, it works for me when I copy paste your examples... I'll add a screenshot, maybe you missed something. Otherwise maybe you should give more details about your text source format.

Comment: It works for me, too.  In fact, you shouldn't need to select dot-matches-newline mode; `\s+` handles those.

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, the following pattern seems to match what you want:

```
DEVICE_1\s*\n.*ZONE_2
```

Use `/DEVICE_1\s*\n.*ZONE_2` to jump to the next match.

Use `:g/DEVICE_1\s*\n.*ZONE_2/command` to execute `command` on each match.

Use `:vim DEVICE_1\s*\n.*ZONE_2 % | cw` to list all the matches in the quicfix window.

Note that you can easily reuse the latest search pattern with `//`. It is a common strategy to work on your search pattern with `/foo` and, once you are satisfied, perform a substitution like this:

```
:%s//bar
```

Comment: +1 for the nice search result overview: `vimgrep|copen` I usually do :g yank or register redirection. learned something from you. AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

There you go for Vim:

```
/^\zssrc.type= DEVICE_1\ze\_.\{2,2}\_^dst.type= ZONE_2$/
```

Breakdown of important expressions:

1. `\zs` - Start match here (will be highlighted from here);
2. `\ze` - End match here (will be highlighted to here);
3. `\_.` - same as `.`, but new line is also included;
4. `\_^` - like `^`, but `\_` is required because we are in the middle
   of regular expression.

For others, I'd refer you to Vim's documentation.